# django models to model 'has-a' and 'contains' relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following entities:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    pass


class FooBar(models.Model):
    pwned_foo = # Foobar contains one Foo object
    bars = # Collection of Bar objects
```

How do I express the relation between Foo, Bar and FooBar in the FooBar class?

Comment: use relationships like onetoone relationship

Comment: pwned_foo = ForiegnKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE) and bars = ForiegnKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: @vSugumar FooBar has a **1-1 relationship** (?) to *Foo* via `pwned_foo`, but has a **1-N relationship** with *Bar* via `bars`. I don't see how your last comment reflects this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) and a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foobar = models.ForeignKey(FooBar, related_name='bars')


class FooBar(models.Model):
    pwned_foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo)
    bars = # Collection of Bar objects
    # you can access bars via the reverse relationship like
    # myfoobar.bars
```

This assumes you want a `1-N` relation with bars. If you want an `N-N` relation, then use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).

If you really need to keep `Bar` clean of any relationship (can you explain why?) you could try something like [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) with the caveats that this only works on postgresql, and you would need to reimplement relationships in querysets, etc... And I suspect performance would suffer too...

Comment: I think you're heading in the right direction, but I don't like the *implicit* injection of `FooBar` into `Bar`. This is not good design, as there is no conceivable reason why `Bar` should be so tightly coupled to `FooBar`. Ideally, `Bar` should be completely agnostic of which ever class decides to keep collections of it.

Comment: The thing is that these models map to database tables and relations, which is why it's done this way. See my edit in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
   pass


class FooBar(models.Model):
    pwned_foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bars = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. `bars` will not provide a list of `Bar` objects here.

Comment: @LaurentS, so what field type will provide a list of bar objects to FooBar then?